# Pick form field values and calculate totals using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with these rows:

```
                <td> - </td> 
              <input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_2_item_type" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][2][item_type]" type="hidden" value="other" />
                <td><input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_2_description" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][2][description]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_2_quantity" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][2][quantity]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short format-currency" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_2_rate" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][2][rate]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short format-currency" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_2_amount" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][2][amount]" size="30" type="text" /></td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
            <input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_3_invoice_id" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][3][invoice_id]" type="hidden" />

                <td> - </td> 
              <input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_3_item_type" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][3][item_type]" type="hidden" value="other" />
                <td><input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_3_description" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][3][description]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_3_quantity" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][3][quantity]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short format-currency" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_3_rate" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][3][rate]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short format-currency" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_3_amount" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][3][amount]" size="30" type="text" /></td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
            <input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_4_invoice_id" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][4][invoice_id]" type="hidden" />

                <td> - </td> 
              <input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_4_item_type" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][4][item_type]" type="hidden" value="other" />
                <td><input id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_4_description" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][4][description]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_4_quantity" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][4][quantity]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short format-currency" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_4_rate" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][4][rate]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input class="short format-currency" id="invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_4_amount" name="invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][4][amount]" size="30" type="text" /></td>

          </tr>
```

I'd like to be able to pick the values from the quantity field, rate field and then calculate the amount which will be displayed in the "_amount" textfield. The amount field should be locked to prevent users from altering the values. Apart from a for loop how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a css class to either one of the input fields or the table rows, and then use `$.each()` to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP to do the actual calculations. Pass all field values to a PHP script using AJAX. I would recommend using jQuery's [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function and [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function together. Now for the PHP make sure you set your locale first.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,'en_CA');
```

Now grab all the costs and multiply each one by their quantity. You now have a Number but you want it in currency format. Use the [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function.

```
echo money_format('%n', $cost);
```

I use echo because you are sending it back to JavaScript with the AJAX return. Finally to stop users from editing a form field use the read-only attribute or hidden type.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="hidden" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is going to be a purely Javascript, the backend is irrelevant at this stage since it could be any of the languages available

Answer (score 0):

If you put the number at the end instead of the middle: i.e.

```
invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_rate_2
```

instead of

```
invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_2_rate
```

Then you could do something like:

```
$('input[id^=invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_rate],' + 
       'input[id^=invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_quantity]').change(
        function() {
            var grab_n = new RegExp('/[0-9]+$/');
            var i = parseInt(grab_n.exec($(this).attr('id')));
            $('#invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_amount_' + i).val(
                 $('#invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_quantity_' + i).val() *
                 $('#invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_rate_' + i).val() );
        });
```

And make the amount field read only. (Remember to check it on the php side anyway, in case the user doesn't have javascript enabled, or is trying to cheat.)

Comment: changed the HTML and added that code, I keep getting a "callback is undefined" error, any idea why?

Comment: I think the code above should be:
$(document).ready(function(){

$( 'input[id^=invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_rate], ' + 'input[id^=invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_quantity]' ).each(
 function(){
  $( this ).bind (
   "focus",
   function(){
   var grab_n = new RegExp('/[0-9]+$/');
   var i = parseInt(grab_n.exec($(this).attr('id')));
   $('#invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_amount_' + i).val(
                 $('#invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_quantity_' + i).val() *
                 $('#invoice_invoice_line_items_attributes_rate_' + i).val() );
  });
 
});
  
  
});

Comment: I updated the code to fix the "callback is undefined" error. It shouldn't have been $.each(...).change(...), just $(...).change(...)